# get the second crash Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131362944 after the first crash

Tags: android, crash, androidx, unmarshalling

let say, I have 2 activities (activity HomeActivity and activity B). HomeActivity contains 3 fragments inside a viewpager, while B doesn't contain any fragments.
from HomeActivity  I open activity B, then activity B get crashed, the system bring me back to HomeActivity with the second crash as the logs below.
please note that I run my app in debug mode with proguard dissabled.
anyone please help me to overcome this problem, thank you very much.

```
2020-10-17 11:13:56.638 21382-21382/com.example.stg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.stg, PID: 21382
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.screen.homescreen.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@169c0a5: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131362944 at offset 932
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@169c0a5: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131362944 at offset 932
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2945)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:3327)
    at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:2484)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2923)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3244)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
    at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1029)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.restoreState(FragmentStateManager.java:226)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2459)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState(FragmentController.java:196)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:287)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at  com.example.core.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:28)
    at com.example.screen.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:18)
    at com.example.screen.homescreen.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:78)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have similar one.